# ShaderToy's FragCoord.xy value and more

Tags: vector, glsl, coordinates, webgl

As a computer graphics task we were assigned to translate some ShaderToy filters into our teacher's personal language, but I can't find any documentation or tutorial that can help me with many of the new stuff that I keep encountering, I managed to get to a good point by myself with some research but now I'm stuck!

My questions are:

`FragCoord.xy` what exact value returns? (With `vec2 FragCoord = {i, j}` if I guessed correctly).

If I divided `FragCoord.xy` by 720, what `vec2` value would be returned?

Thanks

Comment: Not exactly, what I need to know it's not what FragCoord is for, but what FragCoord.xy returns! A vec2? A float? What is the structure of the returned value? (i, j)? i+j?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.xy` is called [Swizzling](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Data_Type_(GLSL)#Swizzling):

> You can use x, y, z, or w, referring to the first, second, third, and fourth components, respectively.

That means `FragCoord.xy` takes the `x` and `y` component of `FragCoord` and creates a vector of type `vec2`. It is even possible to use components multiple times (e.g. `FragCoord.xx`, `FragCoord.yy`) or to change it's order (e.g. `FragCoord.yx`).

---

GLSL binary [Operators](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/GLSL_Programming/Vector_and_Matrix_Operations#Components) work component-wise. Therefore `FragCoord.xy / 720` can be replaced by `vec2(FragCoord.x / 720, FragCoord.y / 720)`.

Comment: Now I get it! So when divided by 720, it becomes a (i/720, j/720) right?

Comment: @B.Castarunza Yes, GLSL binary [Operators](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/GLSL_Programming/Vector_and_Matrix_Operations#Components) work component-wise.

Comment: Now that I think about it, if I have a vec2 called V, what's the difference between calling V and V.xy? (Asking this since FragCoord is a vec2)

Comment: @B.Castarunza There is no difference. But if you are not sure (for what ever reason), if it is a `vec2` or `vec3`, then there is a difference. It can also improve the "readability" of the program.

Comment: Thank you for the quick feedback! Have a wonderful day!

Comment: @B.Castarunza Thank you. You're welcome. Is the issue solved?

Comment: Yes, I keep forgetting to check the answer :,)